# Do not understand how to position UI rectTransform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I do not understand what i am doing wrong here. I am trying the following:

1) Positioned 4 x Images (Cards) on UI scene

```
public Image aceHeartZone, aceClubZone, aceDiamondZone, aceSpadeZone;
```

2) The ace-cards are in the same hierarchy, in the Editor, as the normal cards:

[image]

3) I copy the positions from the AceXX cards to Vector2 properties

```
zone10 = aceHeartPos.rectTransform.localPosition;
zone20 = aceClubPos.rectTransform.localPosition;
zone30 = aceDiamondPos.rectTransform.localPosition;
zone40 = aceSpadePos.rectTransform.localPosition;
```

4) On the cards i have the following snippet:

```
_x = _prep.zone10.x;
_y = _prep.zone10.y;
myRectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(_x, _y);
```

5) And the card is not positioned correctly:

[image]

Behind the actual cards-images is the ace card-images, which is from where i pick the positions

**QUESTION:**
What do I do wrong here?

Comment: Depends on your setup. Are both sets of positions in world-space, or screen-space? Are you sure you're not mixing two coordinate systems? --- Is the origin/root of both image sets the same? ie center, or same corner? If the root is in a corner, are the images themselves the same size? Assuming top-left is the origin, are you sure the ace cards' images don't have a transparent border/overhang, which leads the normal cards to be positioned with a top-left offset (at the edge of the transparent part)? --- With the limited info you provided, it's near impossible to know what's wrong...

Comment: Please, check the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UICreateFromScripting.html) and read carefully the **Positioning the UI element** section. Moreover, If you take a closer look at your code, you will see that you are trying to assign a `rectTransform.localPosition` to a `rectTransform.anchoredPosition`

Comment: Correct comment on "localPosition" vs. "rectTransform", i copied my test. There is now difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thank you all. I feel pretty stupid I must say as i should have figured this out immediately. Problem is that I did mix localPosition and anchoredPosition!!!

I now changed everything except the drag code to anchoredPosition and it works.

Well, at least i learned something that I should have seen immediately...